# Authenticating to CP 'stuck' on EE 3/4/5

Tags: control-panel, authentication

On EE 3/4/5 sites using Chrome, upon submitting for authenticating to the CP, I get infinite "Loading". If I refresh the web page, though, I'm in. Any ideas why this is happening? The fix is easy (refreshing), but this is just sort of annoying, and I hope it's not symptomatic of worse things.

Comment: I have the same problem on many of my EE site. Maybe it's a server problem?!  I also use the refresh solution

Comment: Maybe. I'm using LAMP. You?

Comment: No. It's  a vps.